# Unable to populate Select list via JQuery. Environment: MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-selectors, razor

I'm using MVC3 application with Razor ViewEngine. I've a form with few RadioButtons and a Select listBox. On the basis of selected radiobutton, I am getting a list of Areas from the controller. This list is then used to populate the select list by putting Title as Value and ID as ID. The problem I'm having is that my select list shows [object] [Object], instead of Area Name.

```
<div>
@Using Html.BeginForm()
@<fieldset>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Label("Airport")
        @Html.RadioButton("Opt1", "AIR", True)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Label("Seaport")
        @Html.RadioButton("Opt1", "SEA", False)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Label("Hotel")
        @Html.RadioButton("Opt1", "HOT", False)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Label("Postcode")
        @Html.RadioButton("Opt1", "PC", False)
    </div>

    <select id="SelectionValues" name="SelectedValue" size="width: 100px">
        <option>
        </option>
    </select>

</fieldset>
End Using

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":checkbox, :radio").click(function () {
        var type = $('form input[type=radio]:checked').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetAreasByType',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { type: type },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#SelectionValues').empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    var opt = new option(result[0, i], result[1, i]);
                    $('#SelectionValues').append(opt);
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

On Controller side I've the following function:

```
<HttpPost()>
Function GetAreasByType(ByVal Type As String) As ActionResult
    Debug.WriteLine(Type)
    Dim areas = _areaRepository.GetAreaByType(Type)
    Debug.WriteLine("========================================")
    For Each a In areas
        Debug.WriteLine(a.ID & " " & a.Title & " " & a.Type)
    Next
    Debug.WriteLine("========================================")
    'Return Json(areas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    Return Json(areas)
End Function
```

NOTE: The Output window is giving the correct result.
RESULT of Output window:

```
PC
========================================
EC1 4AF EC1 - Westminister PC
RH6 8RJ RH6 8RJ PC
SE18 6HX SE18 6HX PC
SE8 4AF SE8 4AF PC
========================================
```

On Repository side I've the following:

```
Public Class AreaRepository
    Implements IAreaRepository

    Private _areas As New List(Of Area)

    Sub New()
        _areas.Add(New Area With {.ID = "SE18 6HX", .Title = "SE18 6HX", .Type = "PC"})
        _areas.Add(New Area With {.ID = "SE8 4AF", .Title = "SE8 4AF", .Type = "PC"})
        _areas.Add(New Area With {.ID = "RH6 8RJ", .Title = "RH6 8RJ", .Type = "PC"})
        _areas.Add(New Area With {.ID = "EC1 4AF", .Title = "EC1 - Westminister", .Type = "PC"})

        _areas.Add(New Area With {.ID = "Hot-1", .Title = "Holiday Inn Express", .Type = "HOT"})
        _areas.Add(New Area With {.ID = "Hot-2", .Title = "IBIS Hotel", .Type = "HOT"})
        _areas.Add(New Area With {.ID = "Hot-3", .Title = "Marriot Hotel", .Type = "HOT"})
        _areas.Add(New Area With {.ID = "Hot-4", .Title = "Shariton", .Type = "HOT"})

        _areas.Add(New Area With {.ID = "Sea-1", .Title = "Dover", .Type = "SEA"})
        _areas.Add(New Area With {.ID = "Sea-2", .Title = "Portsmouth", .Type = "SEA"})
        _areas.Add(New Area With {.ID = "Sea-3", .Title = "Plymouth", .Type = "SEA"})

        _areas.Add(New Area With {.ID = "Air-1", .Title = "Gatwick", .Type = "AIR"})
        _areas.Add(New Area With {.ID = "Air-2", .Title = "Heathrow", .Type = "AIR"})
        _areas.Add(New Area With {.ID = "Air-3", .Title = "Luton", .Type = "AIR"})
    End Sub


    Public Function GetAreaByType(Type As String) As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Area) Implements IAreaRepository.GetAreaByType
        Dim var = (From a In _areas
                   Order By a.Title Ascending
                   Where a.Type = Type
                   Select a).ToList()
        Return var
    End Function
End Class
```

Please guide, what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 success: function (result) {
    $('#SelectionValues').empty();               
    $.each(result, function (index, elem) {
        $('#SelectionValues').append(
           $("<option/>").attr("value", elem.ID)
                            .text(elem.Title)
                    );
                });
               }
```

also set the `dataType:'json'` so the json you receive is parsed

Comment: how does your `result` look like, have you set the `dataType:'json'`?

Comment: No Mate, I'm new to these things. Controller Method is posted above. Regards